# ReferenceError: function is not defined even if function is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't manage to understand this error and remove it.

As seen from firefox dev tools when I resize the screen:

```
ReferenceError: checksize is not defined
```

I don't understand why firefox says my function is not defined. It's bizarre...

```
// Display info on cards hover or click according to view
  $(document).on('page:change', function () {
    $('#collapseOne').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
    });
    $('#collapseOne').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(".glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
    });

    // run on initial page load
    checkSize();
    // on screen resize
    window.addEventListener('resize',function () {
      console.log('Resize of screen has been identified');
      // All the taxing stuff you do
      checksize();
    });

     function checkSize() {        
        // Use jquery intent to prevent ???
        // Source-stackoverflow.com/questions/1089246/how-to-tell-hover-to-wait &
        // cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html
        $(".card-image").hoverIntent({
            sensitivity:100,//sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
            interval:100,//milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
            timeout:100,//milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
            over:function(){
              $('.card-short-info',this).slideToggle(100);
            },
            out:function(){
              $('.card-short-info',this).slideToggle(300);
              // remove behind the scene appearance on small screen that would linger when moving to large screen

            }
        });

      }

    });
```

Comment: You've used `checkSize` in the declaration and `checksize` in the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive.

You need an `S`.

Comment: Ashamed is my second name... hopw did I miss this?

Comment: will upvote in 5 min

Answer (score 0):

Take the definition of checkSize() out of the $(document) block.